# function for converting kilograms to pounds and ounces

Tags: javascript, data-conversion, units-of-measurement

I'd like to convert kilos into pounds and ounces e.g. if a user enters 10 kg then the function should return 22 lb and 0.73 oz

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to take a user input value in and convert it and output it into another textbox, is there a convert button,do you want the output into the same textbox..these are questions not clear

Comment: @TStamper: I think it's clear enough--help the man with the function; he doesn't need to say if he has buttons or not.

Comment: @Yoooder, how is it clear if he needs help to convert, the reason it is not clear because if a button calls the function convert and where is the output going to, not sure if he just wants the function of how, or help with the whole thing

Comment: I was just after a function, I should have made that more clear in the question. I've left community wiki switched on if you'd like to edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I *think* he really wants help converting 22.12345 lbs into 22lbs and 3oz

Comment: @Tom- that is not the reason for community wiki, questions can be edited by higher rep users regardless, cw is for questions that tend to be subjective, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow for more detail

Comment: @TStamper ah I see, I thought it was just for clarification as someone edited one my previous questions for that reason. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @dlamblin's answer, here's a function that returns the pounds and ounces in a structure.

```
function kToLbs(pK) {
    var nearExact = pK/0.45359237;
    var lbs = Math.floor(nearExact);
    var oz = (nearExact - lbs) * 16;
    return {
        pounds: lbs,
        ounces: oz
    };
}

var imperial = kToLbs(10);
alert("10 kg = " + imperial.pounds + " lbs and " + imperial.ounces + " oz.");
```

Here's how you would go the other way:

```
function lbsAndOzToK(imperial) {
    var pounds = imperial.pounds + imperial.ounces / 16;
    return pounds * 0.45359237;
}

var kg = lbsToK({ pounds: 10, ounces: 8 });
alert("10 lbs and 8 oz = " + kg + " kg.");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function kgToPounds(value) {
    return value * ?conversionValue?;
}
```

Replace `?conversionValue?` to whatever the rate needs to be.

```
function poundsToOunces(value) {
    return value * 16;
}
```

Not really hard stuff, this.

Comment: Might not be hard for yourself, for conversions always confuse me thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function KtoLbs(pK) {
  nearExact = pK/0.45359237;
  lbs = Math.floor(nearExact);
  oz = (nearExact - lbs) * 16;
}
/* sigh */
```

Answer (score 1):

Google almost does it.  Wont do pounds and ounces.

Google "10 kg in ounces"

Google responds: 10 kilograms = 352.739619 ounces

Then all you'd have to do is write all the plumbing to send the info to google and get it back.

:-)

Comment: That seems like a really expensive way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

this is an easy conversion... I will leave the details to you....

[1 kilogram = 2.20462262 pounds](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS307US307&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=convert+kg+to+lb)